# Why are all the javascript files in my rails app being put into single js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So we have an app made with rails that we are we are deploying to Heroku. We have been having very odd CSS, JS issues on the heroku build of our app. We noticed that currently all JS files are in one single 22000 line file after compiling our files. Did we 'mis-compile'? Messed up file structure possibly? Thanks, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: It really depends of your front project builder usually builders like webpack or parcel do that but you can alway customize and get back the same file structure without the concatenation

Comment: What you are seeing is a feature. I suggest you ask a different question with the actual problem you are having.

Comment: The actual question is why is it mixing up CSS rules, and certain ones are lost all together.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say it is an odd issue? According to the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#main-features):

> Sprockets concatenates all JavaScript files into one master .js file and all CSS files into one master .css file.

What you call an 'issue' seems to be a 'feature'.

Comment: Could this 'feature', cause issues?

Comment: What sort of issues?

Comment: Agreed, it's perfectly normal. Remember that nowadays things are being transpiled and minified and who knows what else. It's not like the old days, where you just wrote code and pushed it. Rails is taking care of you, don't worry :D